# viewControllers show function not being called from inside another file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewController (testViewController) and UIView (called resultsTableView). There is a tableView inside resultsTablView that has this function for when a row is selected:

```
let testViewController = TestViewController()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    testViewController.presentUser()
    print("row selected")
}
```

and inside of testViewController I have this:

```
func presentUser() {
    print("present called")
    show(userProfileVC(), sender: self)
}

func test() {        
    show(userProfileVC(), sender: self)
}
```

When I select a row inside resultsTableView, the `presentUser` function gets called because "present called" is printed, but `show(userProfileVC(), sender: self)` does not show the viewController. I added a test button inside of resultsTableView which called `test()`, and that did end up showing `userProfileVC()`. How can I fix this issue? If you need more code/information let me know.

Comment: Your problem is that you are creating a new instance of your `TestViewController` in your results table view and calling the function on that instance,but that is not the instance that is on the screen. You need to use a delegation pattern with the TestViewController instance setting itself as the resultsTableView’s delegate.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: where have you added testViewController to the view stack? when is testViewController shown?

Comment: testViewController is the first/main view controller